# Google Domain with A name record is pointing to Google nameservers but wordpress GCP vm installation won't resolve to the domain

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

The domain is registered with Google Domains and is pointing to the correct nameservers by default for Google Cloud Platform. I created DNS records pointing to the IP of the VM in the Google Domains DNS settings.

The VM is a Bitnami Wordpress installation on GCP

The VM works on it's assigned IP address, but does not resolve when trying to use the TLD. I changed the hardcoded wordpress site URL using SSH.

I am looking for a solution to this, I am sure it is something quite easy that I am overlooking

Comment: It can take time for DNS changes to propagate to intermediate servers. Does the domain resolve elsewhere (externally) as expected? If so, what DNS is the VM using, and how does it respond to dig/nslookup queries?

Comment: Given @user2864740 comment about time to resolve, you will need to show your records/settings at the registrar and the DNS servers. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide domain name?